# C++ - Trying to pass object by references makes its members dereference

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference

So I'm writing a class, which contains references to two objects like so:

```
private:
 Poly *p1, *p2;
```

Then I construct the class like so:

```
rati::rati() : p1(new Poly()), p2(new Poly()) {
    (*p2)[0] = 1;
}

rati::rat(Poly &p1, Poly &p2) : p1(&p1), p2(&p2) {
}
```

and I overload the `<<` operator for printing like so(as a friend function, of course):

```
using std::ostream;

ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, rat &r) {
    return stream << *(r.p1) << "--------------------------" << std::endl << *(r.p2);
}
```

`Poly` class overload `<<` as well(and successfully, for once).

When I use the default constructor, it works perfectly.  However, if I use the second constructor, it throws `SIGSEGV`. I've debuggedd it and it seems like when I reach this last line:

```
rat r = r1*r1+r2;
cout << r << endl;
```

It reaches it without problems, these are the properties:

```
r.p1->d = 10
r.p2->d = 7
```

like it should.
But then, when I enter `ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, rat &r)`, 
it seems like `r.p1` and `r.p2` are de-referenced:

```
r.p1->d=6683600
r.p2->d=6683536
```

If it helps, I use `g++` compiler, but it happens on `Visual Studio 2019` compiler as well.

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:

I've tried to overload `=`:

```
rat& rat::operator=(rat r) {
    this->p1 = new Poly(*r.p1);
    this->p2 = new Poly(*r.p2);

    return *this;
}
```

The thing with `r.p1->d` happened again. By the way, the weird thing is that `r.p1->d` is defined as `const`. 
 I've tried this too:

```
rat& rat::operator=(rat const& r) {
     this->p1 = new Poly(1);
    return *this;
}
```

but it seems that as soon as I declare a new `Poly`, the values change(or it is de-referenced.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You have ownership issue: How do you know if you might/should call `delete p1`?

Comment: Do you really need pointer, Isn't `Poly p1, p2;` better?

Comment: Create a [mcve]. This can probably easily be fixed by using smart pointers (or simply removing the indirection entirely).

Comment: I'm guessing that the objects you pass to the constructor get destroyed before your last call to `<<` (can't be sure though, since the relevant code isn't in your question)

Comment: Your destructor is presumably doing `delete p1` and `delete p2`.  If the objects passed to the non-default constructor are not both created with operator `new`, the `delete`s will have undefined behaviour.   Also, look up the "rule of three" - your class will need to have hand-rolled copy constructor and assignment operator, otherwise copying an object will create two objects that refer to the same `p1` and `p2` - so those objects will be deleted twice to, again, give undefined behaviour.

Comment: I have no destructor on purpose. No delete is occurring either. I've shared all the relevant code, and since I've debugged it, I know it something with the way it's passed to `operator<<`..

Comment: btw, the reason I use pointers is because I cannot change the `Poly` class and I want to bypass its assignment overloading.. I figured I could do so with pointers.. Do you have a better idea though?

Comment: I've added more information

Comment: rat& rat::operator=(rat r) { when this function is called the parameter is a temporary copy, which is deleted afterwards, leading to double deletion. Try: rat& rat::operator=(rat const & r) { this->p1 = new Poly(*r.p1); this->p2 = new Poly(*r.p2); return *this; }

Comment: yeah, my mistake. That is n't the cause though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it..
Changed constructor to:

```
rat::rat(Poly &p1, Poly &p2) : p1(new Poly(p1)), p2(new Poly(p2)) {
}
```

and now it works!

I guess I had to just copy it and still without using the assignment operator.